# How to get an attribute from a JSONObject in a jsp with Struts2?

Tags: json, jsp, struts2

I have the following situation:

```
  <s:iterator var="doc" value="docList">
    <tr>
       <td class="lastm">${doc.get("attribute")}</td>
    </tr>
  </s:iterator>
```

`docList` is an ArrayList of JSONObjects.

When I load my page I get the following error:

> The function get must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified

I've also tried doing
    `<td class="lastm">${doc.attribute}</td>`

but then I get the following error instead:

> Property 'attribute' not found on type org.json.JSONObject

What am I doing wrong? 
The ArrayList has been originally built from a bigger JSONObject that contained the smaller "docs", but I needed an Iterable object to build my table. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

Instead of using

```
<s:iterator var="doc" value="docList">
   <tr>
      <td class="lastm">${doc.get("attribute")}</td>
   </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

I can do

```
<s:iterator var="doc" value="docList">
   <tr>
      <td class="lastm"><s:property value="#doc.get('attribute')"/></td>
   </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Looks like it works!

Answer (score 0):

`<s:property value="attribute"/>` should also work.